# Defining a value with type constraints while keeping narrow type of the value in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to declare a value that extends specific type and keeps its narrow type at the same time.

Is there a way to achieve this without calling a function?

```
const stringRecord : <T extends Record<string, string>>(x: T)=>T= (x) => x;


//Define value that extends Record<string, string> without calling a function 
const abc = stringRecord({
      a: "a",
      b: "b",
      c: "c"
  });


//Type should remain {a: string, b: string, c: string}
type ABC = typeof abc;
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBLATgSwgcwEoFNyICZwBccAPACpxYAeMWEeUc2ueJSqaANAjCugHz8AFFWJkAlAF5%20ZSXBHi40uFQDcwUJFhwAhgCMQSnn0w4w%20IQG9gcW3ds7iAIh1PON%203b3O9bj57gQZxAnfzgAX3F1YBgATwAHLDgAQQAhAGEjOMSwADNdA1UgA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wjJg1w) work for you?    If so I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on what use case it fails for.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it is an interesting idea, but I am looking for something that could be expressed in a single assignment expression and without the use of typeof operator

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to mention that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently (as of TypeScript 4.4) no type operator which checks that a value is assignable to a given (non-[union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) type without also widening it to that type.  There is a longstanding open feature request for such an operator at [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481).  If you want to see this happen you might go to that issue and give it a  or describe your use case and why the existing workarounds aren't sufficient; but I don't think it's likely that a single additional voice there will have much effect.

For now there are, unfortunately, only workarounds.

The remainder of this answer will discuss some of them briefly; although since they are not acceptable to you, you may ignore it.  Consider the discussion academic, or possibly helpful to future readers.

---

The workaround from your question, using a helper function, is a good one in my opinion.  It has some minimal runtime impact, but it's not too cumbersome to use.

---

If you don't want any runtime impact at all, you could write some type functions to do something similar but purely in the type system:

```
const abc = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: "c"
};

type ABC = typeof abc;
type Extends<T extends U, U> = void;
type TestABC = Extends<ABC, Record<string, string>>; // okay
```

The `Extends<T, U>` type function doesn't evaluate to anything useful (it's just `void`), but it will throw a compiler warning if `T` does not extend `U`.  Observe:

```
const abc = {
    a: "a",
    b: 123, // <-- not a string
    c: "c"
};

type ABC = typeof abc;
type Extends<T extends U, U> = void;
type TestABC = Extends<ABC, Record<string, string>>; // error!
// ------------------> ~~~
// Property 'b' is incompatible
```

And all the extra stuff gets erased at runtime.

---

Finally, the simplest workaround is just to ignore the constraint entirely and rely on something elsewhere to throw a compiler error.  That is, if you write just

```
const abc = {
    a: "a",
    b: "b",
    c: "c"
};
```

and move on, presumably somewhere else in your code base you will use `abc` in a place that expects a `Record<string, string>`.  Perhaps by passing it to some function you actually want to use:

```
declare function doSomethingLater(x: Record<string, string>): void;
```

If it works with no compiler warning, then great:

```
doSomethingLater(abc); // okay
```

If not, the warning will tell you what was wrong with `abc`:

```
doSomethingLater(abc); // error!
/* Argument of type '{ a: string; b: number; c: string; }' is not 
assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string>' */
```

If no code in your code base complains when `abc` is not assignable to  `Record<string, string>`, then you might want to step back and consider why that is.  Maybe you don't actually need such a constraint because the code doesn't care.  But if the absence of a warning doesn't imply that everything's fine, then you might need to fall back to one of the previous workarounds.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAMgIZTYBOAFAB4BciASthHFcgDwDOUVhIgBpEfAcQB8ASkQBvRAF8AUErBkcPAA5kI2RAHUOAax5yliC4nZg+iMgCMIiALxnL7u0wBEZL0PMeFvbe9n4BgRDeEF7higDciCruUACemnoAggBCAMIuiKnpcMB2jnGxhXoAonSUYMg8XAAqiNi12PWmAKoiXRL5AG5wMMjlyWl6Tdh82XmuNXUNXLMirOycvPyCImKCEhIJAPSHiHBGZClJlqgYOPiC5JS0DhBSRydnFyrKKmoa2rpEAAxMgwAA2plksWsthe+ShgQsZG8vn8iMQwUQAEYAEwAZhEx0QXAAtCTEGA4FA7KItsRYu5IogvNFYgpyhUJohZvlKsVShAxpZKogFh0li02otur1+q4hiMhRYRVMZrl8mLOstcqs2BxuLtiDs6UR9u9WlQqBwAISxIlkh2Op2O-oAP3ddpOAAUrekqKlEAByeyBxAwUyEdiYbSwexgvRXCw3LC4AjER7UGgvN6IInUK1UW3uQ4AKm5VCIIBwYGp-JFgfkyNp4iICUxYCr9moCSZhtbilD4YpVMS7jIPB4MCIajjeigcEQ2io6lw1FOJXra31mxbxpbElDJcO3yAA)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!